# How to automatically spin a 3d hsitogram in matlab?

Tags: matlab, animation, 3d, histogram

I have a 3d histogram in matlab.  Is it possible to automatically spin it i.e to get the 3d effects. I want to show it as a video in PowerPoint where the 3d histogram swivels.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat cumbersome way to do this would be to rotate the chart manually using the [`view`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/view.html) command.  You can update azimuth and elevation views of any 3D plot using this command.

Creating a video of it requires capturing the plot window using a command sequence like this (note, you're going to get the gray background, so you might want to change the background color):

```
% create figure and get handle to it (store handle in hf)
hf = figure(1);

% [create 3d plot]

% Create file to hold the animation
aviobj = avifile('mymovie.avi', 'compression', 'Cinepak');

% loop with some criteria for rotation
while(...)
    % update view using view command
    view(az, el);

    % get Matlab to flush the drawing buffer (effectively forces a plot update)
    drawnow;

    % capture frame and write to the avi file
    aviobj = addframe(aviobj, hf);
end
% end loop

% Close movie (flushes write buffer and finishes the video)
aviobj = close(aviobj);
```

You can use the same tactic without the `avifile` stuff to rotate the plot using a script in Matlab, though you might want to use a `pause` command to slow down the frame change.

Answer (score 0):

Let us make sure we are talking about the same thing here.  A 2-D histogram would have bins of a specified X and Y range and the count would be shown on a Z axis. A 3-D histogram would have bins in the X and Y and Z ranges with the count shown in some other way (color?)  You would need slicing for a 3-D histogram to make sense.I am going to assume that you mean a 2-D histogram that looks like a bunch of blocks coming out of the ground.

I think you will be better served to make this 2-D histogram into an image, where each pixel represents a specific bin in X and Y and the color specifies the count in that bin.  I think the motion will only confuse the data.  Use image or imagesc or imshow for this.  Also, I would recommend an intensity based colormap (>>colormap), like spring or winter.  This make the differences more apparent.  Turn on the colorbar (>>colorbar)